# How to search for files based on ACL or group permissions

Tags: mojave, acl

There are double entries for the group 'everyone' under permissions. This is the state of hundreds of files in the Documents Folder. I don't know how they got there and it's now a big problem for my workflow since upgrading to Mojave [10.14.6] as I have to enter a password if I want to move this file into another folder or move it to the trash.

[image: Double of group 'everyone']

I can remove the extra group this way:

`Mac-Pro:~ user$ chmod -N /Volumes/Mountain_Lion/Users/rjrasch/Documents/Cantare\ Docs/Cantare\ Logo\ samples.pdf`

Once I remove the ACL permissions with chmod -N I can move and/or discard the file without a password.

[image: Custom permission removed]

I noticed the man find page list -acl as a primary but I have not been able to create a valid command to locate other files that need this permission removed.

What Unix command do I need in order to search for other files in the Documents Folder so I can fix these types of permissions?

Comment: The following will list all the files that have an access control list- `find ~/Documents -acl` Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: That did the trick. My error was trying to add parameters after the -acl in order to target the everyone group. I am using this command to find and fix:
$ find ~/Documents -acl  -execdir chmod -N {} \;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, the command to find and remove ACL permissions in the Documents directory is:

```
find ~/Documents -acl -execdir chmod -N {} \;
```